# How to make two non-convex Kinematic Rigidbody Colliders detect eachother?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies, mesh-collider

Essentially I'm making a 3d inventory system where you can drag and drop objects, and i'm trying to make it so it detects when you are overlapping two objects.

The objects require a rigidbody to work at all, and can't be kinematic since they are non-convex, making the mesh collider convex makes for a collider that is inaccurate to the mesh itself.

Currently nothing happens in my OnCollisionEnter and OnCollisionExit statements when i make these two collide, they completely ignore eachother but they collide fine with another box-shaped trigger.

How would i go about this? I already tried turning on *Enable Contact Pairs* in the physics settings in the project settings but no luck.